# Movement when dual wielding

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

When dual wielding, can the character move in between the attack with the main hand and the off hand attack?

Comment: related: [monk movement between attack and flurry of blows](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56056/23970)

Comment: very closely related, but not duplicate since GWM feat's wording gives a different answer: [can a GWM move between attack and GWM-granted bonus attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48121/23970)

Comment: and then two more questions about how to order/sequence/break up attacks, bonus actions, and movement: [action surge to dash between attacks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79555/23970), [bonus action attack during Attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72888/23970).

Comment: Finally, think I found the duplicate target. Marijan, if the linked question does not answer your question please [edit] this one to make clear the distinction between the two. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you get to break up your movement and do some before, some after, and even some between attacks.

Quoting [the SRD](http://5e.d20srd.org/srd/combat/movementandPosition.htm) on movement:

> ### Breaking Up Your Move
>
> You can break up your movement on your turn, using some of your speed before and after your action. For example, if you have a speed of 30 feet, you can move 10 feet, take your action, and then move 20 feet.
>
> ### Moving between Attacks
>
> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks. For example, a fighter who can make two attacks with the Extra Attack feature and who has a speed of 25 feet could move 10 feet, make an attack, move 15 feet, and then attack again.